# JavaFX ToggleButton is not visible but registered as Children

Tags: java, javafx, togglebutton, invisible, jfoenix

im creating a JavaFX based Discord Bot where you can choose which Guilds are allowed to listen to Commands, and it creates as many ToggleButtons as the amount of Servers the Bot is connected to.
Here is my Method:

```
public void generateButtons() {
    int y = 14;
    discordVBox = new VBox();
    JFXToggleButton tglBtn;
    discordVBox.setSpacing(30);
    for (final Guild g : DiscordBot.jda.getGuilds()) {
        if (g == null || g.getTextChannels().isEmpty() || !DiscordBot.isDiscordBotOnline()) {
            PrintConsole.printError("Error creating Toggle Buttons.");
            return;
        } else {
            tglBtn = new JFXToggleButton();
            tglBtn.setText(g.getName());
            tglBtn.setStyle("-jfx-toggle-color: #d35400;");
            tglBtn.setLayoutX(14);
            tglBtn.setLayoutY(y);
            tglBtn.setPrefHeight(56);
            tglBtn.setPrefWidth(141);
            discordVBox.getChildren().add(tglBtn);
            y += 63;
            System.out.println("DISABLED: " + tglBtn.isDisabled());
            System.out.println("VISIBLE: " + tglBtn.isVisible());
            System.out.println("PARENT: " + tglBtn.getParent());
            tglBtn.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("VBOX PARENT: " + discordVBox.getParent());
    System.out.println("VBOX CHILDREN: " + discordVBox.getChildren());
}
```

Ignore all the outputs, i was trying to debug all of them and per code it seemed fine, but no visible to the eye.
The Scene itself is mostly via FXML and im using a Custom Library for JavaFX called Jfoenix
The Method "generateButtons" is executed as soon the Discord Bot goes online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually the NEW VBox you created that is not visible.

If you loaded the scene with FXMLLoader, all of the scene contents were created for you and references were provided to the loaded objects. Use the VBox that you specified with the FXML code instead of creating a new one.

You can remove line 3 of your sample code and this should run.

```
discordVBox = new VBox(); // <- don't need this, there is already an VBox instantiated
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i had this problem for days!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: @James_D sorry, im new to Stack Overflow.